# HLS Playback Issues on Android with FFMPEG

Tags: android, ffmpeg, http-live-streaming

I am using the FFMPEG built of AppUnite with the latest patch for stagefright support in order to playback http live streams: https://review.appunite.com/#/c/1779/

As the stream does not start at 0, I added the following code to avoid a black screen:

```
struct Player {
   + int64_t video_start_time;
}

void player_get_video_duration(struct Player *player) {
+ player->video_start_time = 0;

+ for (i = 0; i < player->capture_streams_no; ++i) {
+    AVStream *stream = player->input_streams[i];
+       if (stream->start_time > 0) {
+          player->video_start_time = av_rescale_q(
+             stream->start_time, stream->time_base, AV_TIME_BASE_Q);
+
+          LOGI(3, "player_set_data_source stream[%d] start_time: %ld",
+             i, player->video_start_time);
+
+           break;
+       }
+   }
}

enum WaitFuncRet player_wait_for_frame(
   struct Player *player, double time, int stream_no) {
- int64_t current_time = av_gettime();
+ int64_t current_time = av_gettime() + player->video_start_time; 
}
```

However, as soon as the sleep_time in player_wait_for_frame drops below 0, playback freezes and then hangs waiting for a frame that never arrives. The queues allocated by player_alloc_queues function seem being not big enough to hold the real-time stream pushed in between player_open_input and player_start_decoding_threads. Increasing the number of nodes in the queue does not resolve the issue however. The issue seems to be clearly in the player_wait_for_frame method but I am unable to find a solution.

I spent quite a lot time trying to resolve this nasty issue, but without success so far. Any help really appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

i got the same problem using that library. In my case i was trying to play a DVB stream forwarded over the network. The stream is live and sometime (because of network problems or other reasons) some packets could be missed or corrupted, and the library stop to play.

To get it working i did other 2 fixes in addition to the "video start time fix" (the patch in your post).

The first one is disable the "stop stream on decoding failure":

```
@@ -1112,7 +1127,7 @@
            av_free_packet(packet_data->packet);
        }
        queue_pop_finish(queue, &player->mutex_queue, &player->cond_queue);
-       if (err < 0) {
+       if (!player->is_live_stream && err < 0) {
            pthread_mutex_lock(&player->mutex_queue);
            goto stop;
        }
```

The second one is disable the PTS adjustment for frames who arrive too late (in a live stream we must drop them):

```
@@ -738,7 +741,19 @@
                "player_wait_for_frame[%d] Waiting for frame: sleeping: %" SCNd64,
                stream_no, sleep_time);

-       if (sleep_time < -300000ll) {
+       if (player->is_live_stream && sleep_time < -1000000ll) {
+           // 1000 ms late
+           int64_t new_value = player->start_time - sleep_time;
+
+           LOGI(4,
+                   "player_wait_for_frame[%d] skipping frame because too late",
+                   stream_no);
+
+           ret = WAIT_FUNC_RET_SKIP;
+           break;
+       }
+
+        if (sleep_time < -300000ll) {
            // 300 ms late
            int64_t new_value = player->start_time - sleep_time;
```

The "player->is_live_stream" is an int 0/1, i set to 1 when i'm playing a live stream, so for other kinds of sources the library still work as before.

Hope this can help you :)